# Google oauth2 shows approval prompt on every login

Tags: authentication, oauth, go, google-api, google-oauth

The problem is oauth2 login not works properly using https://github.com/golang/oauth2/ library.

Github works great and not shows approval prompt after once I've approved.
But Google oauth2 shows approval prompt on every login.

Below url is golang oauth2 generated auth URL. And I didn't find the problem with it.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=redirect_url&response_type=code&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.profile.emails.read&state=state
```

The document(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) said default approval_prompt value is auto.

I've approved the API Testing app properly.
And confirmed it from permissions page(https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions)

And then, https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth shows approval prompt again.
I've double checked approval_prompt is not 'force'.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the token in a file and check on the start of your application, whether the token is still valid or not. You only need to show the approval prompt if the token is outdated.

This is the how I did it. The relevant code can be found [here](https://github.com/davidrjenni/taskfs/blob/master/auth.go#L50).

Answer (score 0):

"If you're using the Google strategy with Passport.js, you can enhance the authentication process by adding the { prompt: 'select_account' } option while routing. This can provide a smoother experience for users who have multiple Google accounts or need to re-authenticate.

When using the passport.authenticate('google') method, you can include this option as follows:
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { prompt: 'select_account' }));

By adding { prompt: 'select_account' }, you ensure that users are presented with a screen to select their Google account if they have multiple accounts logged in, improving user experience and avoiding potential confusion."
and at last can see your redirect url where prompt will be 'consent' if prompt is still 'none' please ensure that you have properly implemented above code or not.